# Generating random numbers in ink!

Tags: ink, random

I've been trying to use most common

```
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
let winner_pos = rng.gen_range(0..10);
```

way to get a random number and use it in one of the contract's messages. But it throws a bunch of errors like:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `u128` cannot be known at compilation time
   |
26 |         bids: ink_storage::Mapping<AccountId, Balance>,
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

which are pretty misleading.

What is an alternative way to generate a random number then?

Comment: Also a note on this, you can't use libraries like `rand` since they typically get entropy from the operating system, which is not accessible from the context of a smart contract running on a blockchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `self.env.random()` to get the random seed associated with the block. However, any commitments using this [must be implemented in previous blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/868#issuecomment-886151547).

For example, if you're contract offered betting on the outcome of a dice roll, you would need to ask the bettors to bet at block `n`. The outcome of the bet is then calculated at block `n+2` using `self.env.random()` to generate the dice roll outcome. The value of `self.env.random()` at block `n+2` can be used because it was unknown at block `n`.

If you're trying to generate a random number between a min and a max, you can use something [like this](https://github.com/prosopo-io/protocol/blob/c56b61987be7a6929e81dcd1eaa182b522d2248e/contracts/lib.rs#L1315-L13220). In this example, the user account is passed to `self.env.random()` to create additional randomness.

Answer (score 2):

I think ink_env, no longer provides support for random: https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.3.0/ink_env/#functions

What should be used for the moment?

Comment: there is article from Astar where we can generate random number in range [here](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/builder-guides/xvm_wasm/pseudo_random/)

Comment: thank you @Ganesh11 this is exactly what I was looking for. Weird that this isn't included in the official documents